# Ubuntu 14.04 / VMware - initial screen size

Tags: 14.04, vmware, login-screen, display-resolution

When VMware Workstation starts my Ubuntu 14.04 image, there are 3 screens that it goes through.  There is a) the terminal mode (runlevel 3) where the system boots.  There is b) the initial login screen.  Then there is the sctual c) desktop.

Setting the screen resolution in the desktop is easy.  What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to have the VM start in a specific size in a and b, which would match what I've already set in c.  My goal is to have all 3 phases remain in the same window size.

Thanks!